# Group by on part of composite key

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I want to find the cheapest wholesaler for each article only using this table:

**Table Article_Wholesaler**

```
article_id     wholesaler_id        price
1                    1               500
1                    2              1000
2                    1               300
```

The primary key is composed of the article_id and the wholesaler_id.

Is there any way to achieve this with using the min function?

This query doesn't actually return the correct wholesaler_id, but in order to use this query as a subquery I need both parts of the Primary Key...

```
select aw.article_id, aw.wholesaler_id, min(aw.price) as min_purchase_price
from Article_Wholesaler aw
group by aw.article_id;
```

Thank you for any help :).

Comment: what dbms are you using?

Comment: just a simple mysql

Comment: See [_Groupwise Max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) (or MIN, in your case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subselect with group by

```
  select aw.article_id, aw.wholesaler_id, aw.price
  from Article_Wholesaler aw 
  where ( aw.article_id, aw.price in ( select  article_id, min(price)
                                        from Article_Wholesaler
                                         group by article_id )
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't use group by for this.  You can do:

```
Select t.*
From t
Where t.price = (select min(t2.price) from t t2 where t2.artickeid = t.articleid)
```